# I am able to move to my Profile page without login by just changing the url address in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web

I am new to angular i am building an login page that will redirect to the User Profile page  after successful login but I am able to move to the next page with just changing the url address without any login and by clicking back button i come on my login page 
Here is My code

User.js Controller

```
$scope.login = function(data){
    console.log('from form',data);
    UserService.login(data)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.serverMessage = '';
        console.log('resp',response);
        $location.path('/userprofile')
        var user = response.user;
        var sessionObj ={'user':response.user};
        sessionObj.user.password = data.password;
        $cookieStore.put('User',sessionObj);
        console.log("--------",sessionObj);
    }).catch(function(err){
        //$scope.serverMessage = "Username and Password does not matches"; // for display server msg
        $scope.error = err.message;


    })
}
```

Here is Services:

```
this.login = function(data){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
  console.log(baseUrl+'/api/user/login');
    $http.post(baseUrl+'/api/user/login',data)
    .success(function(response){
        $rootScope.user = response;
        deferred.resolve(response);
    })
    .error(function(err){
        deferred.reject(err);
    })

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here is App.js(Route Controller)

```
    angular
   .module('a2BClientApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
  ])
 .config(function ($routeProvider) {






$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'

  })
  .when('/userprofile', {
    templateUrl: 'views/userProfile.html',
    controller: 'UserProfileCtrl',
    access: { isFree: false }
  })
  .when('/forgotPassword', {
    templateUrl: 'views/forgotPassword.html',
  })
  .when('/decline',{
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Can You please Help me Out where Should I write Conditions so that it should not directly go to the next page by simply changing the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your api needs to have an authorization check in place so that the user has to be logged in in order to fetch his profile if that is not public data, or if that particular route presents private data that shouldn't be available to the public. As for the client-side code, you can use the `resolve` property on the route and make sure they are logged in before allowing it:

```
 .when('/userprofile', {
    templateUrl: 'views/userProfile.html',
    controller: 'UserProfileCtrl',
    resolve: {
      isLoggedIn: function(UserService, $location) {
        // this should return a promise that resolves or a value
        var loggedIn = UserService.isLoggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
          return loggedIn;
        } else {
          $location.path(goSomewhereElse);
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: so i need one API for checking isLoggedIn  ? can't we check directly and redirect according to that. Is there any way of Checking with $cookieStore?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. The server should be able to identify a user and reject the request if they aren't logged in. That's a separate matter from the client-side code. On the client-side, you need to set a flag when the user logs in and check it when needed. If the flag hasn't been set, the route won't load. @TongShen's answer works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should add login status check by listening to the `$routeChangeStart` event. Like this:

```
angular.module('a2BClientApp', [])
  .run(['rootScope', function(rootScope) {
    rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, currentRoute) {
      if(!shouldAllow()) {             // check if user should be allowed in
        event.preventDefault();        // prevent the route change to happen
      }
    })
  }]);
```

[Docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeStart)

Answer (score 0):

Remember too to check server-side for the incoming request. Any moderately sophisticated user could thwart client-side code. If you are using MVC, you would need to check for the authToken there via an action filter and return a 401 unauthorized. Since I don't know what your backend is, I'm not going to offer a code sample. but this might be a good read: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Cheers